# Does RDP clipboard transmit securely on port 3389?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

You can cut and paste text/files from/to remote session and it goes through port 3389. What is the encryption, if any?

I am using Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782610.aspx - it is at least TLS 1.0 (as of 2005), but I believe that if you set it to Negotiate (which is default), RDP will pick highest possible encryption.

Comment: A newer article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2011/12/08/encryption-negotiation-in-rdp-connection.aspx (still not great)